# Kubernetes - keeping the execution logs of a pod

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to keep the execution logs of containers in Kubernetes.

I added in my cronjob yaml the `successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5 failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5` in order to see the execution history, but when I try to view the logs of the pods I get this error

[image]

I assume it is because the pods have been deleted because when I go to a running pod I can see the logs.

[image]

So is there a way of keeping the logs in this part of Kubernetes or is there something that I have to setup in order to have this functionality?

Sorry if the question have been asked but I didn't really find something and I'm new to Kubernetes.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this problem in a bigger picture it's generally a good idea to have your logs stored via logging agents or directly pushed into an external service as per [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures).

Taking advantage of Kubernetes logging architecture explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level) you can also try to [fetch the logs directly from the log-rotate files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#system-component-logs) in the node hosting the pods. Please note that this option might depend on the specific Kubernetes implementation as log files might be deleted when the pod eviction is triggered.

Comment: Hello, I didn't voted down the answer, I don't know who did. I'm currently reading the documentation that he sent me.

Comment: I think that I may have been to broad on the question. The cronjobs I'm executing are just shell scripts so using services like fluend or grafana may be complicated. Is it possible to just save the logs into a file with a kubernetes option in the cronjobs yaml configuration file ? A second I thought of was to use docker / kubernetes volumes to store the logs and then use it.

Comment: @EmileDadou Have you managed to find a suitable solution based on my answer?

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko not yet, I'm currently on other projects and I didn't really had the time to work on this one. But i'm using the ressources you sent to guide me.

Comment: @EmileDadou gotch ya, if you find that answer useful you can upvote/accept it.